# What's the difference between "get it" and "got it"?

Tags: meaning, differences, confusables

They are not "I get it." or "I got it.". They are only "Get it." and "Got it.". I'm wondering what's the difference between them.

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is between *get* and *got*, or why the expression is *Got it* and not *I got it* ?

Comment: Like the one between "I can see what you mean" and "Now I see what you mean" (You didn't see till now). Get it? :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach The difference is between get and got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Get it* on its own would normally only be used as either an imperative (telling someone to get something) or a question (asking if someone understood; *[do you] get it?*). *I get it* (meaning *I understand*) is not usually shortened to *get it*.

---

*Got it* can be used in a few more ways. As a statement (*[I've] got it*), it means that the speaker understands, or the speaker physically has something, or (in a similar way to *I've got this*) that the speaker has the situation under control.

As a question (*[have you] got it?*) it can be used to ask any of the above: if someone understands (the same as *get it?*), if they physically have something, or if they have the situation under control (like *have you got this?*).

Comment: Yes. The 'teacher' could ask either "Get it?" or "Got it?", but the learner could only choose "Got it!" out of the two.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:  Unless of course the student is parroting the teacher sarcastically!  "Get it?" asked the teacher.  "Get it?" said the student mockingly.

Comment: @Samthere:  You're welcome.  I gave you an upvote for your appreciation.